# How do I call a C++ Function from Assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm writing a C++ program, that requires some custom assembly code.

I write the assembly code like so

```
__asm
{
    //Code Here
}
```

I would like to be able to call a C++ function within the assembly, so like call

```
MyFunction(eax, ebp).
```

Comment: Call your C++ function from C++ code, view the dis-assembly and you'll know for sure (P.S.: some IDEs require that you run your code and stop with a break-point, in order to give you the `view dis-assembly` option).

Comment: BTW, different compilers yield different assembly code (typically depending on the underlying HW architecture that the compiler is designated for). So you should indicate the platform that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what instruction set you're talking about. But provided that instruction set supports it, you could
1. Declare and initialize the function pointer in your code
2. Use call or jump kind of instruction to execute from the memory address pointed to by the function pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function if you observe the calling conventions. Here an example for Visual Studio 2010 (32-bit):

```
#include <iostream>

char* txt = "Hello world";

int myfunc2 (char* s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int myfunc1 ()
{
    char* s = new char[80];

    __asm
    {
        mov ebx, s                      ; = mov ebx, [ebp -4]
        mov byte ptr [ebx], 'H'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+1], 'e'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+2], 'l'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+3], 'l'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+4], 'o'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+5], 0         ; Don't forget the terminator!

        push s
        call myfunc2                    ; Call the function above
        add esp, 4

        push txt
        push s
        call strcpy                     ; Function of C-library
        add esp, 8

        push s
        call puts                       ; Function of C-library
        add esp, 4

    }

    delete[] s;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    myfunc1();
    return 0;
}
```